# Can dummy X server be forced to use integrated graphics?

Tags: drivers, graphics, xorg, teamviewer

I have a headless desktop running Ubuntu 22.04 which needs to be accessible via Team Viewer. To do so, have followed the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1322937/ubuntu-20-04-shows-a-black-screen-when-connecting-through-teamviewer-but-i-stil), having installed `xserver-xorg-video-dummy` and created the following xorg config at `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`:

```
# This xorg configuration file is meant to be used
# to start a dummy X11 server.
# For details, please see:
# https://www.xpra.org/xorg.conf

Section "Device"
        Identifier  "Configured Video Device"
        Driver      "dummy"
        #VideoRam 4096000
        #VideoRam 256000
        VideoRam    16384
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
        Identifier  "Configured Monitor"
        HorizSync   5.0 - 1000.0
        VertRefresh 5.0 - 200.0
        Modeline "1920x1080" 23.53 1920 1952 2040 2072 1080 1106 1108 1135
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier  "Default Screen"
        Monitor     "Configured Monitor"
        Device      "Configured Video Device"
        DefaultDepth 24
        SubSection "Display"
                 Viewport 0 0
                 Depth 24
                 Virtual 1920 1080
        EndSubSection
EndSection
```

This actually works great. But visual applications are quite slow, and upon inspection have found that the graphics device under GNOME system info is `llvmpipe (LLVM 15.0.6, 256 bits)`. From what I can gather, this is very basic rendering driver, not what should be running on the integrated graphics processor.

```
$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: CoffeeLake-S GT2 [UHD Graphics 630]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:a0000000-a0ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-graphics
       product: EFI VGA
       physical id: 2
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       capabilities: fb
       configuration: depth=32 resolution=800,600
```

```
lspci -k
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core 4-core Desktop Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers [Coffee Lake S] (rev 08)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core 4-core Desktop Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers [Coffee Lake S]
    Kernel driver in use: skl_uncore
    Kernel modules: ie31200_edac
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation CoffeeLake-S GT2 [UHD Graphics 630]
    DeviceName: Onboard - Video
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation CoffeeLake-S GT2 [UHD Graphics 630]
    Kernel modules: i915
```

```
$ glxinfo -B
name of display: :1
display: :1  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
    Vendor: Mesa/X.org (0xffffffff)
    Device: llvmpipe (LLVM 15.0.6, 256 bits) (0xffffffff)
    Version: 22.2.5
    Accelerated: no
    Video memory: 7849MB
    Unified memory: no
    Preferred profile: core (0x1)
    Max core profile version: 4.5
    Max compat profile version: 4.5
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.2
OpenGL vendor string: Mesa/X.org
OpenGL renderer string: llvmpipe (LLVM 15.0.6, 256 bits)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 22.2.5
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile

OpenGL version string: 4.5 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 22.2.5
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile

OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 22.2.5
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
```

The machine has no dedicated graphics card, but can I get it to use the integrated graphics? Or is it already using them? Changing the "Device" identifier and driver in `xorg.conf` only results in a broken x server, and I have to drop to a TTY session and reset the file or remove it.